# "No bootable device found” after changing motherboard

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, asus

My friend's computer was diagnosed with a broken motherboard and a broken power supply and they recommended her to buy a new one. She doesn’t have the budget to do that, so on my recommendation she bought a new motherboard (ASUS Prime H410M-K) and the power supply. I installed these 2 pieces and now I’m facing the problem that the disc is not recognized as a bootable device. Following google hints I was looking inside the BIOS anything related to legacy/IDE but there aren’t any references. She runs Windows 10 on that PC; the HDD is SATA.

My friend now contacted a technician to help us out. He said that one needs to save the disc’s content and format it all over again. The motherboard she had used before is from a different brand.

Can someone please confirm that this is the right way to do it and if there aren’t other smoother ways?

The HDD is recognized in BIOS and I can even see the directories. I even connected my HDD from another ASUS Motherboard computer, but the disc wasn't recognized as bootable neither.

Any hint is highly appreciated.
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows boots from the harddisk based on what ID the port has it is connected to on the botherboard. If you unplug a SATA cable and plug it into a different port on the same computer with same motherboard, Windows will not boot and you get the exact same as what is happening now.

It is possible to reconstruct this by typing `bcdedit /create` from a command prompt.

Given that swapping out a motherboard will cause driver issues, it is better to reinstall windows anyway, which will solve the issue too.

My advice therefor is going to be, backup all data and reinstall Windows.

Comment: OK. Great explanation. I kind of remember that back in the SCSI days switching discs was far easier.